# Optimizing for garbage collection of large collections

Tags: java, list, collections, garbage-collection

I am reading from database a large collections of this type `List<Rows<Long,String,ByteBuffer>>`

I then read the data from these list of rows one by one and put the data from them into container objects. **Should I de-reference the individual rows, in the list, to null as I move ahead with reading each of them** OR **should I finally de-reference them finally** so that they can be garbage collected ?

Since each row is quite big consisting of large strings/blobs/ text content etc I am trying to optimize for garbage collection. I hope this is not called the premature optimization !?

Comment: I am afraid to say that it is called `premature optimization`. Did you check your JVM usage stats on how long the gc is taking on average?

Comment: nope I am not using JDBC. I didnt checked any stats but are there any disadvantages of pointing to JVM about the variables that are no longer required? What may be the penalty here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As larsmans said, this is the very definition of premature optimization.  However, questions like these often pop up and rather than forgetting about them I like to add profiling points right away (wrapped by an on/off switch - like Logger.isEnabled()) and then move on.  Look at http://netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html for an easy profiling tool/setup

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't **measured** your program's performance, then it's a premature optimization.

(Not every optimization performed before measuring is premature, but these kind of micro-optimizations are.)

Comment: are there any disadvantages of pointing to JVM about the variables that are no longer required? What may be the penalty here ?

Comment: @Marcos: the penalty is that your program becomes more complicated, so you'll spend more time writing, maintaining and compiling it than you save when running it. (It may actually become slower at run-time as well due to poor locality of reference and other factors, but that's hard to predict.)

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest dereferencing them.  this is not premature optimization because unlike time, the amount of memory available to your program for accomplishing its is not as much under your control.

Comment: obviously some of the other answerers don't understand optimization or premature optimization.  the analogy from time/CPU to memory hardly carries over perfectly.  even if it did, the asker clearly states that the rows are large blobs, and you are reserving N of them in memory.  next, the risks are asymmetrical, the cost of garbage collection is proportional to live objects (proportional to the size of the N blobs), so if your platform gets virtual-memory constrained, your gc might be copy-collecting N large blobs very frequently causing your program to essentially freeze. just not same as CPU

Comment: The memory used by a string is mostly a character array; by a ByteBuffer, mostly some sort of byte array. Neither of those contains pointers, and so neither will be scanned by the collector. Furthermore, even if they were, if they're long-lived, they'll have been moved into the old spaces, which are scanned infrequently, and in which objects are not moved (until they're tenured). The CPU overhead of the existence of these objects is very likely to be very small.

Comment: The point was you are needlessly retaining LARGE chunks of memory, and memory constraints are unpredictable and can seriously ding your program.  If one is taking such a risk just to avoid the costs of nulling a reference, one's understanding of optimization is superficial. (edited for objectivity)

Comment: Your point seems very valid to me and that was the reason I asked here. My blobs could be seriously as big as this entire discussion here. Now my point was to free up the memory as I am done with copying the question or each of the answer from top to bottom, 1st question, then 1 answer and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As larsmans has mentioned, there is the disadvantage of complexity.

But there may also be a performance disadvantage - nulling a reference involves writing to memory, and  in a modern garbage-collected environment, writing to memory is not necessarily simply a store. There may also be some book-keeping for the benefit of the collector - look up 'write barrier' and 'card marking' in the context of garbage collection. Writing also has effects on processor caches; on a multiprocessor system, it will cause cache coherency traffic between processors, which consumes bandwidth.

Now, i don't think any of these effects are huge. But you should be aware that writes to memory are not always as cheap as you might think. That's why you have to profile before you optimise, and then profile again afterwards!